# URL-safe actions in Twilio TwiML responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

For the sake of brevity, I have an endpoint which takes in some parameters, and returns a TwiML response to redirect the call to another endpoint to gather a user's DTMF response:

```
[HttpGet]
public async MyEndpoint<ActionResult> Test(string parameterOne, string parameterTwo)
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse()
        .Redirect(
            url: $"https://example.com/Gather?parameterOne={parameterOne}&parameterTwo={parameterTwo}",
            method: "POST");

    return TwiML(response);
}
```

Which generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Redirect method="POST">https://example.com/Gather?paramaterOne="test"&amp;parameterTwo="test"</Redirect>
</Response>
```

The idea being that Twilio should post it's standard request object to this endpoint, but include my parameters in the query string:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Gather([FromUri] string parameterOne, string parameterTwo [FromBody] TwilioCallbackRequest request)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

**However, the request fails because of the XML-encoded `&amp;` not being understood to be a query string delimeter by the web server.**

Ideally there would be a way to modify the form values of the Twilio request to include the parameters I need to pass, but I don't believe that feature exists.

My questions are:

A. Is there any way to get Twilio to URL encode it's queries?, or

B. What is the best way to accept a query string that is malformed in this way in ASP.NET without erroring before I have a chance to process the request?

Currently my hacky workaround is to send my query string parameters as one big underscore-delimited string and to parse my parameters from it manually, but I doubt this is the best way. I have also considered intercepting requests with OWIN middleware and attempting to modify the query string for this endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Dev Evangelist here...

It looks like you're using both the Twilio and Twilio.AspNet.Mvc packages to return your response. You can also achieve your objective by preparing the response for your Get method without using the Twilio.AspNet.Mvc package. Here's an example:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string parameterOne, string parameterTwo)
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse()
        .Redirect(
            url: $"https://example.com/Gather?paramaterOne={parameterOne}&parameterTwo={parameterTwo}",
        method: "POST");
    var content = new StringContent(response.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = content,
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
}
```

Try this out and let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this returns the following:

`StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
}`

which Twilio dislikes (12100 Document parse failure)

Comment: Quite interesting that you're getting this response. Would you mind posting (or emailing me at corey@twilio.com) the exact code that you're using for both methods? 

Based on the above response, I suspect that the string content is not actually being sent.

Comment: You're right! I had MVC and WebAPI bindings fighting for the same routes. Worth noting, however, that the Twilio XML generator (the `TwiML` constructor) probably shouldn't be messing with the ampersands when it returns XML.